# Search performance mysql

Tags: mysql, performance, search

just as confirmation, what's best for search engine in mysql? Search words or numbers?

Lets imagine a DB of students. Should have a table for students, another for classes and another for registrations (that would associate students with classes with their unique id) or just have a table registrations with all the students data and the classes names?

Only thinking about performance, not worrying about structure and anything else once that all the process is made my a software installed in a computer that synchronize everything with the server.

The point is to create a log of thousands of registration and put it online in a system that would be capable of group classes, students, search for it , made charts and everything. My concern is mysql performance when php starts querying all the data.

What would be better? Search in thousands of rows with IDs and inner join it or search in thousands of rows with names and strings
Best regards

Comment: *"What would be better?"*  simple answer good database design (`normalization`) and indexing then MySQL can handle join's with millions or billions of records just fine, thousands is not alot so don't worry about performance.

Comment: You are really asking about many things here.  For the first point, one of normalization, best practice dictates that you normalize your database.  Most of the time, having a single monolithic table is bad compared with a set of normalized tables representing the same data.  As for optimizing queries, that is whole other can of worms.

Comment: @RaymondNijland actually it is. I'm having problems because the names of students and the names of classes are big. The table currently has 400 thousand records all in strings without thirths tables or inner join

Answer (score 1):

Simple answer:

Avoid non-referenced textual fields whenever you can, along with good measure of indexing dependent on what your database will be used for (warehouse or production) and enforce 3NF whenever and however possible...Lower than 3NF isn't recommended if you're not sure what that entails, while higher than 3NF may prove too complex for you, the human, to always keep a handle on.

Comment: To better clarify: Letting the DBMS use numbers (integers, preferably) instead of anything else is highly regarded as good practice. 
If and when you need to have queries search columns of text, avoid if practical AND possible, having those columns of variable-length. 
Also, the query for searching text should avoid the use of patterns. (= is the fastest operator out there)

Answer (score 0):

The performance difference between numbers and strings is minor.  The major component in performance is how many rows need to be touched.  Also costly is the overhead of another query.

So, this is inefficient:

```
SELECT id  FROM students  WHERE name...             -- grab a bunch of ids
SELECT ... FROM foo  WHERE student_id IN (...) ...  -- then use them
```

This is better, even though it is *logically* doing the same thing:

```
SELECT ...
    FROM students
    JOIN foo  ON foo.student_id = students.id
    WHERE name ...
```